# Toggling Visibility in Vue not working properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, parent-child, visibility

I'm working on a project where I am receiving data from a websocket and then parsing it into an appropriate UI. The problem I'm running into is when I try and toggle the "Components" of a specific "Agent", the show/hide functionality isn't working properly. Right now I have an "AgentsButton" component that lives inside of the "Config" component, when I applied the same logic in the Config (parent) component it worked fine, but for some reason the child component is not doing what I want it to do. Here is the code I have for the child ("AgentsButton") Component.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-row id="agentRow">
      <b-col v-for="agent in agents" md="auto">
        <b-button class="agentButton" @click="compVisible = true">{{ agent.name }}</b-button>

        <b-container v-if="compVisible" id="componentsDiv">
          <h3>Component-Types</h3>
          <div v-for="item in agent.componentTypes">
            <b-row>
              <b-col md="12">
                <b-button type="button" class="componentItem" @click="openModal(item)">
                  {{ item }}
                </b-button>
              </b-col>
            </b-row>
          </div>
        </b-container>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'AgentButtons',
  components: {},
  props: ['agents', 'components'],
  data() {
    return {
      compVisible: false,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    clickEvent() {
      this.$emit('clicked');
      console.log('clickEvent');
    },
    showComponents() {
      this.compVisible = true;
      console.log(`compVisible: ${this.compVisible}`);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There's a lot of information here that seems irrelevant to the question being asked, and the actual problem isn't stated clearly. That being said, I notice that neither of your methods are being called from the template. Your agent button simply executes `compVisible = true`. Perhaps that's related, but again I don't really understand what isn't working.